# (calculus) show the following infinite series diverges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

> $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3n)!}{n!(n+1)!(n+2)!}$$

please explain me how to solve this

Comment: Do the terms approach $0$?  Always a good thing to check.

Comment: And what have you tried?  We don't answer your problems for free, you have to show us what you've tried.  See [How to ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one of the **criteria for convergence or divergence**

Like **ratio test**:

$$ \lim _{ n->inf }{ \left| \frac { { a }_{ n+1 } }{ { a }_{ n } }  \right|  } =\lim _{ n->inf }{\frac { 3(n+1)! }{ (n+1)!(n+2)!(n+3)! } \frac { n!(n+1)!(n+2)! }{ 3n! }} $$

$$ \lim _{ n->inf }{ \frac { (3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3)(3n)! }{ (n+1)(n+2)(n+3)n! }  } =\lim _{ n->inf }{ \frac { (3n+1)(3n+2)(3n+3) }{ (n+1)(n+2)(n+3) }  } =\lim _{ n->inf }{ \frac { (3+1/n)(3+2/n)(3+3/n)(3/n) }{ (1+1/n)(1+2/n)(1+3/n) }  } =\lim _{ n->inf }{ \frac { (3+0)(3+0)(3+0) }{ (1+0)(1+0)(1+0) }  }  $$

In ratio test you have to proof if it is less than 1 or if it is bigger tan 1, here you can see that it is bigger, that means that the series diverges.

(Please proof my calculation)

*Hope this helps!*

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Show that $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{(3n)!}{(n!(n+1)!(n+2)!}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Ratio of consecutive terms is
${3n+1}(3n+2)(3n+3)/((n+1)(n+2)(n+3))
\to 27$
so it diverges pretty violently.